# Overlapping ggplot2 histograms with different variables

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

If I had 2 different variables to plot as histograms, how would I do it? Take an example of this:

```
data1 <- rnorm(100)
data2 <- rnorm(130)
```

If I want histograms of data1 and data2 in the same plot, is there a way of doing it?

Answer (score 7):

You can get them in the same plot, by just adding another `geom_histogram` layer:

```
## Bad plot
ggplot() + 
  geom_histogram(aes(x=data1),fill=2) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(x=data2))
```

However, a better idea would be to use density plots:

```
d = data.frame(x = c(data1, data2), 
               type=rep(c("A", "B"), c(length(data1), length(data2))))
ggplot(d) + 
  geom_density(aes(x=x, colour=type))
```

or facets:

```
##My preference
ggplot(d) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(x=x)) + 
  facet_wrap(~type)
```

or using barplots (thanks to @rawr)

```
ggplot(d, aes(x, fill = type)) + 
  geom_bar(position = 'identity', alpha = .5)
```

Comment: also, position = identity: `ggplot(d, aes(x, fill = type)) + geom_bar(position = 'identity', alpha = .5)`

Answer (score 3):

A slight variation and addition to @csgillespie's answer:

```
ggplot(d) + 
  geom_density(aes(x=x, colour=type, fill=type), alpha=0.5)
```

which gives:
[image]